# waiting for a new line when working with StreamTokenizer (java)

Tags: java, stream

Hi
when i reach the end of the line with StreamTokenizer, how can i make it wait until i have received a new line from the streamer?

i used:`        StreamTokenizer st = new StreamTokenizer(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)));

thanks

Comment: you have asked 12 questions before, you did not even accept just one of them..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.in is line buffered. You cannot get a portion of the line before it is entered.